# How to match private polymorphic variant type outside of containing module?

Tags: pattern-matching, ocaml, encapsulation, polymorphic-variants

I can close the ability to create an instance of variant type outside the containing module with a `private` keyword.

```ml
module Ordinary : sig
  type t = private X | Y
  val x : t
end = struct 
  type t = X | Y 
  let x = X
end
```

I can't create instances of `Ordinary.t` and the following example is uncompilable:

```ml
let f x = if x = Ordinary.X then 1 else 2
```

> Error: Cannot create values of the private type Ordinary.t

But I can match `Ordinary.t` and the following function works fine:

```ml
let f a = function
  | Ordinary.X -> 1
  | Ordinary.Y -> 2
```

For me, it is logically correct and I expect the same behavior from polymorphic variants. I created the analogical module for this case too.

```ml
module Polymorphic : sig
  type t = private [`X | `Y]
  val x : t
end = struct 
  type t = [`X | `Y]
  let x = `X
end
```

But I can't match `Polymorphic.t`. All my tries with error messages are shown below:

```ml
let g a = 
  match a with
  | `X -> 1 
  | `Y -> 2
    
let x = g Polymorphic.x
```

> ```ml
> let x = g Polymorphic.x
>           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> ```
>
> Error: This expression has type Polymorphic.t but an expression was expected of type
> [< `X | `Y ]

```ml
let x = match Polymorphic.x with
  | `X -> 1
  | `Y -> 2
```

> ```ml
> | `X -> 1
>   ^^
> ```
>
> Error: This pattern matches values of type [? `X ]
> but a pattern was expected which matches values of type Polymorphic.t

```ml
let x = match Polymorphic.x with
  | Polymorphic.`X -> 1
  | Polymorphic.`Y -> 2
```

> ```ml
> | Polymorphic.`X
>               ^
> ```
>
> Error: Syntax error

```ml
let x = 
  let open Polymorphic in
  match x with
  | `X -> 1
  | `Y -> 2
```

> ```ml
> | `X -> 1
>   ^^
> ```
>
> Error: This pattern matches values of type [? `X ]
> but a pattern was expected which matches values of type Polymorphic.t

Is it possible to match the private polymorphic variant type outside of the declaration container?
If it is - How? If it is not - Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The essence of private types is that they are private subtypes of a visible type. In particular values of the private type can be coerced with `:>` to the visible type.

So, this works for me:

```
# match (Polymorphic.x :> [`X|`Y]) with
  | `X -> 1
  | `Y -> 2
  ;;
- : int = 1
```

For what it's worth, I think of a polymorphic variant value like `` `X `` to be pervasive, like the number 1234. So `` `X `` and `` `Y `` aren't so much defined in `Polymorphic` as referenced there. I.e., there is no special `` Polymorphic.(`X) `` value that's different from the unqualified value `` `X ``.

But there is a *type* `Polymorphic.t` that's particular to the module. Values of this type can be coerced to `` [ `X | `Y ] `` but not the other way around.

I hope my way of looking at this isn't too wrong :-) And I hope this is helpful.

Comment: I declared `type t = private int` and as result has the same situation. `I.zero :> int` fixes it.